# How to find configurations changes on a SQL server regarding principal and mirror settings?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to find time stamp and login used when changing the principal or mirror settings for a specific database server? It's on a SQL Server 2008 R2 if relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be this is helpful for you
[image]

if with the help of above image you didn't get record then please run below query then follow above image instruction, which works for me

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default trace enabled', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default trace enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

and we can get with the help of sys object, we have to just give the physical path of trace file then we can get all the record of activity

```
    SELECT *
FROM fn_trace_gettable
('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\Log_34.trc', default)
```

Comment: the change history report is empty on that server - tried that